# Redmine: extend controller action in plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, redmine-plugins

Need some help in plugin development.
I've created hook in user/edit form view, added `ballance_amount` to form and have `"ballance_amount"=>"1"`.

How can I extend default update action in user controller?

In `base.class_eval do` I've added `alias_method_chain :update, :ballance`
In `InstanceMethods`:

```
def update_with_ballance
    ballance.amount = params[:user][:ballance_amount].to_f #I have ballance association
end
```

And get this:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `params' for #<User:0x007f972e9379d0>):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:144:in `update'
```

How can I fetch params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the mass-assignment code in the Redmine itself. [Line 135 in the UsersController](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/f9ddb562d58ae98bcc69f74396b028cbc8cce0b1/app/controllers/users_controller.rb#L135) should handle provide you with a simple entry point for your extension, if `balance_amount` is considered a `safe_attribute`. To achieve that, add a patch like the following to the User model:

```
module RedmineBalancePlugin::UserPatch
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      safe_attributes 'balance_amount'

      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    # This method is indirectly called when creating or updating a User
    def balance_amount=(amount)
      balance.amount = amount
    end

    # This could be useful in your view patch, but maybe not
    def balance_amount
      balance.amount
    end
  end
end

User.send(:include, RedmineBalancePlugin::UserPatch)
```

If this example does not help, it would be helpful, if you could provide more code fragments - e.g. the complete patch to the UsersController, to make it easier to reproduce and analyse the issue.